# Derivation of area horizon law for $SAdS_5$ black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, entropy, event-horizon

How can you derive the area horizon law of the $SAdS_5$ black hole? The metric is written as
$$ds_5^2=\frac{L^2}{z^2}[-fdt^2+dx_1^2+dx_2^2+dx_3^2]+\frac{L^2}{z^2}f^{-1}dz^2$$ where $f(z)=1-z^4/z_H^4$
I know that is something in the form of
$A=\int{d^3x\sqrt{-g}}$, but how do you compute it?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score -1):

By "area horizon law", do you mean how to calculate the area of a black hole in living in an ADS$_5$ spacetime?

I think you might be able to follow the generic technique if that is the case. Consider a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma_t$ of your manifold at some fixed time $t$. Now, you need to determine which of the 4 remaining coordinates is unbounded. Let's say it is $x_1$, i.e., $x_1 \in (-\infty, \infty)$. Next, you want to take another hyperslice $\Sigma_{x_1}$ at a fixed $x_1$ of the hyperslice $\Sigma_t$.

The metric of such a sub hypersurface would be

$$ds^2=\frac{L^2}{z^2}(dx_2^2+dx_3^2 + f^{-1}dz^2 )$$

whose volume (and for your case , the area) is $$A = \int \frac{L}{z} \sqrt{f^{-1}} dx_2 dx_3 dz \,.$$

You can integrate this I suppose if you know the limits of integration.

**Edit:**

Things would be simpler if the unbounded coordinate (analogous to radius) is the $z$ coordinate. In that case the metric of the sub hypersurface $\Sigma_{z}$ would be (by setting $dz = dt = 0$)

$$ ds^2=\frac{L^2}{z^2}(dx_1^2 + dx_2^2+dx_3^2) \,.$$

and hence the area of the black hole

$$A = \int \frac{L}{z}  dx_1 dx_2 dx_3\,.$$

Comment: Can someone give the reason for the down vote please?